# \lstinline highlighting error in Texmaker

Tags: listings, texmaker, highlighting

I am able to compile perfectly, and the PDF output is nice. But editing-wise, it gets annoying that Texmaker colours everything after `\lstinline` as if it is a listing. Any quick fix for this?

Here is a quick example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

Hello, \lstinline{world}. This is now colored as if I were still writing inside of a listing. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a quick fix, which is not the best, but it can work until there is something more elegant.

Adding this before `\begin{document}`, and before any call to `\lstinline` (now `\lil`):

```
\newcommand{\lil}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
\newcommand{\dummycommand}{\end{lstlisting}}
```

Basically, next line is just a useless command, but when Texmaker reads `\end{lstlisting}`, it will stop highlighting everything as a listing.

So now, instead of using `\lstinline`, `\lil` is used to avoid the issue.